# WSO2 ESB Lesson Two: Mediating Messages

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, esb, mediator

Stuck at first hurdle.

Just installed WSO2 ESB, & tried to run through the starter tutorial, but the axis2 server fails to start. on issuing "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -Xms256m ... (within bat) the jre just issues the usage statement as if the arguments were bad. Nothing looks obviously wrong, though I think there is an extra \ in  -repo "%AXIS2_HOME%\repository" but fixing has no effect.

WSO2 itself starts but just cant do anything with it, especially if I cant I work through the samples.

Comment: What is the wso2 product you were using and can you please add the error from the log?

Comment: WSO2 is a company name. There are multiple open source products available in WSO2. Which product, which version you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a small configuration fix required to run this in ESB 4.9.0. You can find the fix [in this jira ticket](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-4272).

Comment: Thanks that fixed it, I probably should have worked it out.